# Inheritance of immutable return types when extending traits in multiple levels

Tags: scala, traits

I have the following trait hierarchy. `TraitA` is the root trait, and given that I want my data structures to be immutable, the function `commonUpdateFunction()` has a generic return type. I am not sure if this is the best way. I have two other traits that extend it, adding two other functions. Some classes extend one, some classes extend the other, but some classes need to extend both.

However, I am now running into a problem where because of that generic type thing I am getting illegal inheritance, when in reality I am only doing it to get the right type when updating the data structure to a new one.

Furthermore it seems I cannot pass `TraitA` as a parameter because of this generic type.

```
trait TraitA[T <: TraitA[T]]
{
   self : T =>

   def commonUpdateFunction() : T
}

trait TraitB extends TraitA[TraitB]
{
   def someFunctionB() : Integer = { /// some code }
}

trait TraitC extends TraitA[TraitC]
{
   def someFunctionC() : Unit = { /// some code } 
}

class ClassB extends TraitB 
{
   def commonUpdateFunction() : ClassB = { /// some code } 
}

class ClassC extends TraitC
{
   def commonUpdateFunction() : ClassC = { /// some code }
} 

class ClassA extends TraitB with TraitC  //**this causes illegal inheritance**
{
   def commonUpdateFunction() : ClassA = { /// some code }
}
```

What is the right way to achieve this inheritance on 2 traits while at the same time having immutable updating of data structures with the right types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type parameters aren't your problem here, the problem is that `ClassA` tries to mix in three copies of `commonFunction()`, which differ only by return type:

```
class ClassA extends TraitB with TraitC {
  def commonFunction() : ClassA = { /// some code }
  def commonFunction() : ClassB = { /// some code } 
  def commonFunction() : ClassC = { /// some code } 
}
```

Although the JVM *does* allow overloading on return type, it isn't permitted at compile time - there's just too much chance for confusion (especially if type inference is involved).

The solution is often to use f-bounded polymorphism (as you did with `commonUpdateFunction()`), but it's impossible to show how to do that here given that all your `commonFunction()` definitions are concrete.

It would help a lot to see more "real" code!

---

**UPDATE:** Based on new information from the comments.

Instead of a type *parameter* you might find life easier with an abstract type *member*.  Using `Repr` (for "Repr"esentation) is a common enough convention and used in the collections lib; make sure that this *abstract* type member has a bound!

Stick the other common attributes in here as well:

```
trait Employee {
  type Repr <: Employee

  def name : String
  def id   : Int

  def withName(name: String) : Repr
  def withId(id: Int) : Repr
}
```

sub-traits follow a similar pattern.  There's no need to re-declare other abstract members that keep their signature.  You can also introduce other members as you refine the types here.

```
trait ManagingEmployee extends Employee {
  type Repr <: ManagingEmployee
  def numberOfReports: Int
  def withNumberOfReports(x: Int) : Repr
}

trait SkilledEmployee extends Employee {
  type Repr <: SkilledEmployee 
  def skill: String
}
```

Now make the leaf nodes of our type tree concrete. case classes work well here, though there will sadly be some duplication (macros could possibly help, but that's a different question).

Note how `name` and `id` are made concrete by the class params, the `Repr` type is made explicit via the `=` sign, and the abstract methods have to be explicitly re-defined in each leaf class:

```
case class HrManager(
  name            : String,
  id              : Int,
  numberOfReports : Int
) extends ManagingEmployee {
  type Repr = HrManager
  def withName(name: String) = this.copy(name = name)
  def withId(id: Int) = this.copy(id = id)
  def withNumberOfReports(x: Int) = this.copy(numberOfReports = id)
}

case class Technician(name: String, id: Int) extends SkilledEmployee {
  type Repr = Technician
  def withName(name: String) = this.copy(name = name)
  def withId(id: Int) = this.copy(id = id)
  val skill = "programming"
} 

case class TechnicalManager(
  name            : String,
  id              : Int,
  numberOfReports : Int
) extends SkilledEmployee with ManagingEmployee {
  type Repr = TechnicalManager 
  def withName(name: String) = this.copy(name = name)
  def withId(id: Int) = this.copy(id = id)
  def withNumberOfReports(x: Int) = this.copy(numberOfReports = id)
  val skill = "software architecture"
}
```

Comment: I am a beginner in Scala, so I might be missing some important design principles. What I am struggling to figure out is how to achieve the traditional OO polymorphism while at the same time keeping data objects immutable. This would be the typical example: `Employee` as an abstract class which has the `name` and `employeeId`, with a few classes extending it like `Technician` and `Manager`. The methods to update the `name` or `employeeId` have to create another instance of the same type if it is going to be immutable. On the other hand, the rest of the system has methods which take `Employee`

Comment: In that scenario, you could just make `Employee` a trait and have case class subtypes for `Technician` and `Manager`.  Declare `withName` and `withId` as you did for `commonUpdateFunction` then define in the case classes in terms of the `copy` method.  I'm wondering if you meant for `commonFunction` and `commonUpdateFunction` to be the same thing in your example; because right now they're *very* different

Comment: Yes, my mistake, they should have been the same. Fixed. Yes I get that thing, the problem comes in other places where I just need to use `Employee` as an argument to a method of a totally unrelated class. It wouldn't care about what type of Employee it is. At the moment I just get errors saying that it needs to have the type specified I guess because of the `[T]` thing which is just there as a hack to determine the real type of the immutable class.

Comment: Ah OK, I got what you did. So you declared an internal type which is overridden by the concrete class... nice trick! I will try it out a bit ... thanks for going all the way to explain it. These concepts are a bit hard for us beginners, even if I am very experienced in Java, having immutable objects needs a very different perspective.

Comment: So the "magic phrases" are that it's an `abstract type member` (*not* a `type parameter`), and that it's `type bound` to be a subclass of `Employee`.  The programming in Scala book has a whole section on members vs parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I just did the Coursera FP course so far by Martin Odersky. I guess I have to take it up another level now.

Comment: Any idea why I can't use `Repr` as a return type for a function which returns `this` in the super trait? Wherever I am trying to use the super trait it is also saying that it is expecting `SuperTrait#Repr`... so seems the same problem of the `[T]` all over again!